# Completion Handler Returns Twice

Tags: ios, swift

So I have a function called `grabUserLoc` which grabs the user location.

```
@objc func grabUserLoc(){
    LocationService.getUserLocation { (location) in
        guard let currentLocation = location else { return }
        print("Latitude: \(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude)")
        print("Longitude: \(currentLocation.coordinate.longitude)")
    }
}
```

The function uses this service method, that contains this function.

```
struct LocationService {
    static func getUserLocation(completion: @escaping (CLLocation?) -> Void){
        print("Atttempting to get user location")
        //May need location manager function

        Location.getLocation(accuracy: .city, frequency:.continuous , success: { (_, location) -> (Void) in
            //print("Latitide: \(location.coordinate.latitude)")
            //print("Longitude: \(location.coordinate.longitude)")
            return completion(location)
        }) { (request, last, error) -> (Void) in
            request.cancel()
            print("Location monitoring failed due to an error \(error)")
            return completion(nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Now I have print statements in the `grabUserLoc` function to make sure things are working properly which they are because the user location is being grabbed. However, the print statement as well as the completion block is being run twice so it is running the print statement two times. Did I do anything wrong here as far as my implementation?

Btw I am using thrid party location pod called swiftlocation
https://github.com/malcommac/SwiftLocation

Comment: what do you get in print 2 times?

Comment: I got the latitude and longitude printed twice @ÖzgürErsil

Comment: can be you assign `grabUserLoc` twice in StoryBoard? Check your event binding.

Comment: not using storyboard bro @ÖzgürErsil

Comment: have you placed a break point at where grabUserLoc is called and check where is it being called from?

Comment: its being called once from viewdidload @BenOng

Answer (score 2):

Try to stop location update before completion as it may update location twice that usually happen when you implement didLocationUpdate delegate method of **CLLocationManager**

```
   Location.getLocation(accuracy: .city, frequency:.continuous , success: { (_, location) -> (Void) in
        //print("Latitide: \(location.coordinate.latitude)")
        //print("Longitude: \(location.coordinate.longitude)")

        //Stop location Update here after first call

        return completion(location)
    }) { (request, last, error) -> (Void) in
        request.cancel()
        print("Location monitoring failed due to an error \(error)")
        return completion(nil)
    }
```

OR surround function with once Bool

```
     @objc func grabUserLoc(){

        var once = true

        LocationService.getUserLocation { (location) in
            guard let currentLocation = location else {
                return
            }

          if(once)
          {
                 print("Latitude: \(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude)")
                 print("Longitude: \(currentLocation.coordinate.longitude)")

               once = false;
          }



        }



}
```

Comment: um okay so what would either of those answers look like im sorry

Comment: I am using swiftlocation

Comment: try second option in answer

Comment: I mean the answer works but it seems like more of a hack

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using some third-party framework to get location so I don't know exactly what your code is doing, but this line:

```
Location.getLocation(accuracy: .city, frequency:.continuous , success:
```

has a `frequency` parameter. Maybe that should be set to something other than `.continuous` to just get a single location?

If you want to use the iOS Core Location framework directly, getting a single location is just a call to `requestLocation()` in `CLLocationManager`.

Comment: I edited the question which shows which thridparty I am using are you familar with it

Comment: That framework has a section called "Getting Current Location (one shot)" which will just give you one location instead of a continuous stream.

Comment: But what if I want my app to be continously getting the user location. Seeing as it is a location based app

Comment: ? any idea how i would do that

Comment: I don't know that framework or how it works, but getting a stream of locations using Core Location is incredibly well documented. Maybe it would be easier for you to use the built-in framework instead of a third-party one.